# Express ${x^3 + 2x^2 + 61 \over (x + 3)^2 (x^2 + 4)}$ in partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

$$\eqalign{
  & {x^3 + 2x^2 + 61 \over (x + 3)^2(x^2 + 4)} \equiv {A \over (x + 3)} + {B \over (x + 3)^2} + {Cx + D \over (x^2 + 4)}  \cr 
  &  \equiv {A(x + 3)(x^2 + 4) + B(x^2 + 4) + (Cx + D)(x + 3)^2 \over (x + 3)^2(x^2 + 4)} \cr} $$

so:

$$x^3 + 2x^2 + 61 \equiv A(x + 3)(x^2 + 4) + B(x^2 + 4) + (Cx + D)(x + 3)^2$$

Solving for $B$, making $x=-3$:

$$\begin{align}
 - 27 + 18 + 61 & = 0 + 13B + 0  \\[6pt]
  13B & = 52  \\[6pt]
  B & = 4 \end{align} $$

The other three variables are tricky as there is no value that I can see that is capable of eliminating two and leaving one, I've tried to "compare coefficients" but I am left with more than one unknown so I think the only other options available to me is solving simultaneously with 3 variables (something I do not know how to do), have i missed something that could make this easier to write in partial fractions?
Thank you.

Comment: Once you plug in $B=4$ you can factor out $x-3$ and divide through by it.  Then put in $x=-3$ again to get another coefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the problem right.  I don't think there's a way of avoiding solving a $3\times 3$ system.  However, you can try "nice" values for $x$ to make it a nice system, e.g. $x=0, x=1, x=-1$.

Comment: Ah, I though that I'd have to resort to such a method, thank you.